# Jenkins publish over ssh for running a shell script

Tags: ubuntu, jenkins, ssh

I have a Jenkins job which will copy a war file to remote system. I'm using publish over ssh plugin to accomplish this. All works fine, The war is getting copied to the remote system. After copying the war file i need to run a shell script which is in the remote system. so publish over ssh provides a Exec command for this.

```
sh /home/ubuntu/build/test.sh
```

The script is for removing a deployed war directory inside webapps and then for copying the war to webapps.

But i'm facing Permission denied issues with this. Following is the error I'm getting

```
rm: cannot remove â€˜/tomcat8/webapps/test/WEB-INF/classes/test.propetiessâ€™: Permission denied
rm: cannot remove â€˜/tomcat8/webapps/test/WEB-INF/classes/query.txtâ€™: Permission denied

cp: cannot create regular file â€˜/tomcat8/webapps/test.warâ€™: Permission denied
```

Any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

1. Are you logging in as a user who has the permission? When you ssh, the username and password that you provide must have permissions to access the file on the system.
2. Make sure that the file is executable. `sudo chmod +x` or whatever permissions are necessary. This goes for both the shell script and the war file. This is the cause most likely.
3. If these 2 are not the case then try and run the script from the terminal and see if the same error exists.

When you are done trying these 3 things, update your findings.

The shell script and the war should both be accessible by the user who is executing the command. Easiest and less secure way is to change permissions via sudo and then execute script.

Comment: The log shows just like that. I could execute the script from terminal. Thanks for the command. I will check step 1 and 2

Comment: Yes do tell your findings.